# what does v-play config contains?

Tags: qt, v-play

I started with v-play and create a new v-play project in Qt creater.

First, I looked at the generated code and tried to understand it.

I have a little idea of Qt and Qml and understand the generated `main.cpp` and `Main.qml`

Then I looked at the `.pro` file.

From Qt I know I must add the Qt modules to use them in my program like: `QT += widgets qml` or configure the support of c++11: `CONFIG += c++11`

In the generated .pro file only stand `CONFIG += v-play` and nevertheless I can use `qml` and `widgets`.

My question now is: What does `v-play` all contains or what modules does `CONFIG += v-play` all include? I looked for a documentation but I haven't found one.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `CONFIG += v-play` is just a link to your v-play module that you need to download before you link it to the `.pro` file.
V-Play with all the function is already installed on your System. You just linked it with your Projekt.

Hope this answered your question.